# Redirect STDOUT to STDERR when exit status isn't 0 in Bash

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

The programming language Crystal currently doesn't write to STDERR when there's a compile time failure.  I need to redirect STDOUT to STDERR if the exit status is not 0 and still return the exit status.

Comment: Have you tried `some_bash_command.sh 2>&1`

Comment: Redirections are run **before** a program is started. Exit status is only known **after** that program exits. You can't go back in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken literally, your request is literally impossible: Redirections are performed before a command has started, whereas exit status is only known when it exits.

However, you can *unconditionally* redirect into a buffer, and then write that buffer to either stdout or stderr after exit status is known.

Consider a wrapper akin to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
if output=$("$@"); then
  printf '%s\n' "$output"
else
  retval=$?
  printf '%s\n' "$output" >&2
  exit "$retval"
fi
```

...invoked as (if this is saved as `stderr-wrapper`):

```
stderr-wrapper your-program arg1 arg2 ...
```

Comment: This is so awesome!  Thank you so much!  It didn't have any side effects for the other happy paths.

Comment: There *is* a caveat here inasmuch as this code will eat any NULs that might be included in your program's output (as NULs can't be stored in C strings, which bash uses for in-memory storage). If that's a problem, you might write to a file.

Comment: If the expected output is too big a temporary file might be safer

Comment: This also has the downside that *all* output will be written to stderr if the process terminates unsuccessfully, and no intermediate status messages will be written during the execution of the program at all...if it's worth the cost, one could write a program that reads from stdin, buffers a certain amount (say a line of text), checks that line of input against a regex that matches messages that should be moved to stderr, and then forwards each line to stdout or stderr as appropriate.

Comment: Or maybe you just contribute a patch to fix the issue at its source in that case.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock, ...writing intermediate messages to stderr is *correct*. POSIX guidelines are that stdout should only be used for output -- not status updates, not prompts, not anything else that could be considered "diagnostic". Thus, it's probably a poorly-written tool that's writing things to stdout that should be on stderr in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Roundabout pipe method, which requires `tac` and a harmless `eval`, but neither buffer variables, nor temporary files.

Demonstration script `demo`, using `echo false ; false` to simulate a program that outputs to *stdout* and returns an error code "*1*".

```
#!/bin/bash
out=([0]=/dev/stdout [1]=/dev/stderr)
{ { echo $1 ; $1 ; echo $? ; } | tac ; } | \
  { read x ; eval tac \> ${out[$x]} ; exit $x ; }
```

Proof, using [`annotate-output`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/annotate-output):

```
annotate-output +'' ./demo true ; echo --- ; annotate-output +'' ./demo false
 I: Started ./demo true
 O: true
 I: Finished with exitcode 0
---
 I: Started ./demo false
 E: false
 I: Finished with exitcode 1
```

Generalizing that `demo` into a `stderr-wrapper`:

1. For `bash`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Usage:  stderr-wrapper program [ args... ]
   out=([0]=/dev/stdout [1]=/dev/stderr)
   { { $@ ; echo $? ; } | tac ; } | \
   { read x ; eval tac \> ${out[$((x>0))]} ; exit $x ; }
   ```
2. For *POSIX* shells, (here it's `dash`):

   ```
   #!/bin/dash
   # Usage:  stderr-wrapper program [ args... ]
   { { "$@" ; echo $? ; } | tac ; } | \
   { read x ; eval tac 1\>\&$(((x>0)+1)) ; exit $x ; }
   ```

---

How the `bash` version works:

1. Run the offending program, which outputs to *stdout*.
2. Print the error code right after that, also to *stdout*.
3. Reverse the whole stream with `tac`, so the error code is first.  (Expensive if stream is lengthy.)
4. `read` one line, the error code, store in `$x`.
5. `eval` the `$out` array member that corresponds to the device where the output should go, then re-reverse the output with `tac` to that device.